# Who can see posts and photos I've been tagged in on my timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-photos

Is it possible to allow in my timeline to be tagged in posts but to hide from my timeline every photo where I am tagged? In other words, is it possible to separate confidentiality parameters between photos and other posts?

In Facebook settings I only find the option *Who can see posts you've been tagged in on your timeline?* and whenever I make a change of the audience here, it applies to posts and photos.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there's no way to do that yet. I also want the posts I'm tagged in to be shown on my timeline and the tagged photos to be visible only to me. I've fiddled with my settings a lot of times already hoping I could find something but meh. Let's hope facebook implements it soon.